# Web Service - using OAuth for private website

Tags: web-services

I have a private website and I want to write an app for it in order to learn how to create an app. Is it recommended that I use OAuth to authenticate my app with the service, even when the API will never be for public use? How should I write web services for fully private sites? I just want to offer the functions of the website as an app, but I do not want to make the web service publicly available.

Comment: Which kind of application? I assume an iOS or Android app... Anyway, it may be a good idea, since you are doing it for learning purposes. OAuth or similar authentication protocols are widely used, so learning how to deal with them can be a good thing!

Comment: Yes, but the user will log in to the website and since it is my own app i have not a problem to save the username/password in the app. So is OAuth really useful? What i don't want is, that the user will log in and get a browser windows where he has to grant access. Similar two twitters own application the user should directly log in to the system.

Comment: The advantage is exactly that: you do not have to save the username/pwd in the app, and you can control through your website access right for your app. You do not like the app anymore? Your phone is stolen? You revoke access rights to the app